# Passing data from widget to app

Tags: android, android-widget, android-pendingintent

I'm developing a widget for my app and I'd like to pass specific data from the widget to the app.  The user can add multiple versions of the widget and I need to detect which widget it is coming from so I can show specific information in the app.

What I have works so far, but only if I exit my app completely (repeatedly pressing the back button), otherwise it doesn't seem to be detecting the data being passed in.

This the code I have to pass the data from the widget to the app:

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider  {

    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) 
            UpdateWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds[i]);
    }

    public static void UpdateWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Main.class);
        final Bundle bun = new Bundle();
        bun.putInt("widgetId", appWidgetId);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtras(bun);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, appWidgetId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetText, pendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Getting close to getting this working, thanks to Tal Kanel.  I have an `ActionBar` in my app and following Google's guidelines, I have this code in `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```
if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
          final Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Main.class);
          intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          startActivity(intent);
          return true;
    }
```

If I click on the "back" button in the `ActionBar`, then minimize my app and click on the widget this code is always null:

```
    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null)
    {

    }
```

**UPDATE 2**

Actually, just going back to the main activity in my app causes `getExtras()` to be null.  I have this code in my app widget, that does not pass any extras to the app:

```
    PendingIntent piMain = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, appWidgetId, new Intent(context, Main.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetTitle, piMain);
```

If I click on that part in my widget, then go back and click on the part of my widget that is supposed to pass the extras, `getExtras()` is always null.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

first of all - your application not really close when you pressing back until returning to home screen.  it's just that no activities from your application exists in this stage.
I think it's very important to know that, in case you didn't...

about your problem:
you are trying to launch activity from the widget with the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, that it definition:

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

that means that if your Main activity already running in forground, then when you start the activity from the widget - all other activities on top of this Main activity will be removed from stack, and Main will resume and get into to **Activity.onNewIntent(intent)** callback.

that's why you don't see the data - because the activity don't restart with the new intent, but only get into the onNewIntent(intent) with the new intent you sent.

I'm sure that if you'll put a break point in the onNewIntent(intent) method - you'll see that the intent you sent is delivered there, with all the extra's data.

another problem with your code: check the definition of the Intent.putExtras(boundle) method:

> Add a set of extended data to the intent. The keys must include a package prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".

**it seems like you don't call your key prefix according to the rules**. that's why it's null.

hope it helped you.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This is the first app widget I've created, so I'm still figuring everything out.  You're right, `onNewItent` is getting hit, so I added my code to check for extras in there and it seems to work, but only after the second time I click on the widget.

Comment: @KrisB: that's exactly what suppose to happened - if the activity not in the stack (the first time), then the data received in the "regular way" - via the onCreate() and getIntent(), and in the other times (when the activity already inside the stack) you'll receive the intent threw the onNewIntent()

Comment: You're right, that's exactly how it's working.  I have a check for the extras in both `onCreate` and `onNewIntent`, the problem seems to be when I use `if (getIntent().getExtras() != null)` sometimes `getExtras()` is `null`.  I was expecting `getExtras()` to never be `null` when clicking from the widget.

Comment: Check out the code I added to the OP.  I have a section of my widget that does not pass any extras and the main section that does.  If I click on the section that does not pass any extras, then go back to the widget and click on the section that does, `getExtras()` is always null.

Comment: @KrisB: I've updated my answer. I think I've found why it was null. it explained on the addition to the answer

Comment: No luck.  I added the package name to the extra key names and it's still always null the first time.  Very strange.

Comment: I think I have this as close as I'm going get it.  For 99% of the people using the widget, it will probably work as expected, so it's not worth the time/effort for the fringe users.  Thanks for your hlep.

Comment: @KrisB: indeed strange. but I can offer you one last advice that can maybe solve this strange problem: instead of putting bundle with the putExtras() method, use the intent.putExtra("widgetId", id), and when trying to get it out in the activity use the int widgetId = intent.getIntExtra("widgetId", defaultValue).   after all - you don't really need a bundle, but only one single value.

Comment: @Tal  That does not work.  Only onCreate(), onStart() and onResume() would get called in your scenario.  onNewIntent() would only get called if you fire an intent from the activity, NOT FROM THE WIDGET.

Comment: @IgorG.: if you'll fire the intent with FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP, and you dismissed the activity previously by pressing the home button to navigate away from it, (and not the back button), and the system didn't destroyed your activity yet for preserving memory, then it will return to onNewIntent() callback and will come back to forground. even from a widget