# Send data from widget to activity

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm trying to send data from my widget to my activity.
I've seen several topics about the widget side, but I didn't succeed to get the data in my activity.

See [Passing data from widget to app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377003/passing-data-from-widget-to-app)

In my Activity I try to do in the onStart() method:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if(intent.getStringExtra("he")!=null)
  LogWrapper.debug(MainActivity.class, "DATA "+intent.getStringExtra("he"));
else
  LogWrapper.debug(MainActivity.class, "DATA null");
```

But Intent is always null.

Widget provider side :

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
LogWrapper.info(DefibWidgetProvider.class,"in onUpdate!");
final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

// Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
  int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

  // Create an Intent to launch MainActivity
  Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity_.class);
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  intent.putExtra("he","Hello !");
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

  // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
  // to the button
  RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_defib);
  views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.refreshButton, pendingIntent);

  // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app widget
  appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}
}
```

Context : My app contains a Google map.
I have 2 buttons in my widget, And I want to open the mainactivity and center the map on a special long/lat when the user click one of these buttons.

Could you help me to make this working ? thank you

Answer (score 5):

As per your suggested link, you will get your intent's data inside onNewIntent method,

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}
```

Get your intent data from inside this method.