# Android App Widget Button

Tags: android, android-appwidget

Hi guys can you help about passing data from widget to app. [Send data from widget to activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378814/send-data-from-widget-to-activity) i've read also this existing question but i can't figure out how does app widget send a message using service to trigger the function in my class .

by the way this is process of my widget .
Widget button (homescreen | lockscreen) > button click > send SMS (function in my class) that its.

anyone can help me ?